# Don't understand why EF doesn't allow me to login

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

The team I'm on at work have been working on a new WPF app. We're using Entity Framework to connect to a SQL Server database. We use Windows authentication. It's set up to allow all my co-workers and I to access the database. We can easily get into it using SQL Server Management Studio and the app while debugging with Visual Studio. However, when we try to run the app from a ClickOnce deployment, it fails. I've captured the exception and inner exception. Here's what it says:

> Exception type: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException Exception
>   message: The underlying provider failed on Open.
>
> InnerException type: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException InnerExceptino
>   message: Cannot open database "OurDatabase" requested by the login.
>   The login failed. Login failed for user 'OURADNETWORK\Rod'

I don't understand why EF is having a problem when we can easily authenticate using SSMS, VS, etc. What's the problem and how do we get around this, please?

Comment: are you sure you're connecting to the instance in its correct port ? try explicitly adding the correct port `server\instance,port` to the connection string.

Comment: can you provide your credentials? I got this error message 1- When there was a problem with my connection string, 2- when the remote server had to give permission

Comment: Stavm, we using the default instance on that server. As far as I know we're also using the default port, 433 I believe, for SQL Server.

Comment: Licentia, we use trusted connections to connect to the database. So, once we're logged into Windows in our Active Directory domain, that's all that it should need.